# how to backup partition tables for windows 10 OS

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, backup, uefi

I have plans to uninstall windows play with some other OS and then again put back Windows 10 in the way it is currently on my hardware.
So I want to take backup of partition table currently there is only Windows on this laptop but there are many many partitions and I want things to be as they are currently.
So I want to know how can I take backup of partition tables on an external USB to use later on. My OS is currently Windows 10.

Currently diskpart output shows me following

```
DISKPART> list vol

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     E                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     C   Windows      NTFS   Partition    915 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 2         Windows RE   NTFS   Partition    980 MB  Healthy
  Volume 3     D   RECOVERY     NTFS   Partition     14 GB  Healthy
  Volume 4                      FAT32  Partition    260 MB  Healthy    System
```

Comment: You need all partitions except RECOVERY but if you intend to latter return the computer to its original state then better to include that one as well. With Clonezilla, suggested in the answer below, you can easily backup everything to a file (or a span of multiple files) and then latter do the reverse action by booting Clonezilla media.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) from Oracle and spin up a virtual machine to install the test OS on. This would leave your host (Windows 10) alone.

However, if you really are looking to nuke your current system then Clonezilla may be a decent option. 
It is not a native solution, but Clonezilla ([found here](https://clonezilla.org/)) will do this reliably. You can find details of the process on the website, but essentially it works like this:

1. Download Clonezilla ISO file
2. Create bootable USB stick
3. Boot to Clonezilla Live
4. Make a backup of the disk (sending it to your external HDD)

When you’re ready to “bring it back to life”, you can boot back into Clonezilla Live and restore an image.