# how to use recovery usb created by hp recovery tool to re install windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot, installation, usb-flash-drive, recovery

I created a recovery USB by HP Recovery tool which came pre installed with my laptop as factory software and this tool said in starting I can only use it once to create a recovery disc be it USB or DVD or a hard disk partition or any thing only once. So I took screenshots of whole process so that if some thing goes wrong I can find what went wrong.
Here are screenshots that will help to understand what happened.
[image: hp recovery manager starting]
[image: message to format usb]
[image: preparing disk]
Now here at 96% it was stuck up for long long long time more than 30 minutes I thought some thing happened but finally it proceeded.
[image: hanged at 96%]
but it proceeded to next step that is verification step
[image: verification step]
[image: 100 percent verification done]

I get a pop up like this 
[image: hp pop up from recovery manager]

Now the USB I check it is still plugged in to USB port it is blank.
[image: blank USB]

Here are my BIOS settings

Comment: You should be using the Media Creation Tool in order to create a working Windows installation media.  Any drivers that HP image might have can be automatically downloaded by Windows through Windows Update.  The only driver you might have to download manually is the one for your network device, store that, on a different removable flash drive.

Comment: I do not know how to properly partition the Windows 10 laptop. I am facing problems my laptop is slow https://superuser.com/questions/1507247/what-could-be-cause-of-my-slow-running-laptop-on-windows-10 I asked here how to take backup of partition tables on windows 10 os
https://superuser.com/questions/1511778/how-to-backup-partition-tables-for-windows-10-os when nothing worked then I came to this HP Recovery Media creation tool I do not have that much hard disk to image my laptop using Mecrium Reflect https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/61026-backup-restore-macrium-reflect.html

Comment: @political science Have you tried looking at the drive contents using 'Show hidden files and folders' found in control panel's Folder Options?

Comment: No I did not see the hidden files previously thanks the content is visible now they are all .swm files now what should I do?

Comment: @politicalscience - You don't need to know how to properly partition an HDD.  The Windows installation environment will partition the HDD for you.

Comment: @politicalscience - You should do nothing.  The tool has done what it was programmed to do.  *.swm iles are used by ImageX, the legacy verison of DISM and *.wim files, but your confusion on how to proceed is the reason you should use the Media Creation Tool instead of the HP tool.

Comment: I at a later date would need to put linux on  this machine and the  formatting etc and erasing every thing may be needed so I want to have a rescue USB so that once I finish all the assignments in my university then I would put every thing back to as it was fresh factory install will media creation tool help in achieving this.

Comment: Oh here is a screenshot of how the folder looks in my case with swm files https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/3e6d995d-c845-4728-85c4-003641fc1b4d?upload=true I just want to verify if this USB is working in case of any emergency I will do create another USB with media creation tool I do not know how to take backup of device drivers.

Comment: No way to verify it works other than recover the PC using it. It looks like it finished properly and verified the media 100%, My bet it is good.

Comment: How to use the recovery media you created, see "Perform system recovery" section...>>>>https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04758961#AbT2

Answer (score 1):

I understand the Recovery USB creation process and have made my own here, and that it can only be used once. Since it did not finish (you have the screens) contact HP Support and ask them to supply you with a recovery USB.  You may need it down the road.

Here is what a working Recovery USB looks like:

[image]